# Using sklearn.metrics Jaccard Index with images?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to do some image comparisons, starting first by finding the Jaccard Index. I'm using the sklearn.metrics implementation of Jaccard Index Using the example below with just a small array of numbers, it works like expected.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_similarity_score

#The y_pred represents the values that the program has found 
y_pred = [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1]
#The y_true represents the values that are actually correct 
y_true = [1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1]

iou = jaccard_similarity_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

Though it is giving an error of...

```
ValueError: unknown is not supported
```

When I feed it the two images such as....

```
iou = jaccard_similarity_score(img_true, img_pred)
```

I'm unsure what to do, I tried converting the images to grayscale using OpenCV and making both the images astype(float) with no luck in either case.

Comment: in your simple example, you have 1-d lists. I assume that images are 2-d numpy arrays. try using `img_true.flatten()` and see what happens

Comment: Ah okay yes that worked @JasonStein thank you!

Comment: jaccard_similarity_score has been deprecated and replaced with jaccard_score

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Posting as answer so question can be closed: flattening `img_true` and `img_pred` solved by doing `img_true.flatten()` and `img_pred.flatten()`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ravel()` for converting it into 1-D:

```
img_true=np.array(img_true).ravel()
img_pred=np.array(img_pred).ravel()
iou = jaccard_similarity_score(img_true, img_pred)
```

Comment: ravel and flatten do the same then when called as methods of a numpy array! you can close this question by marking either answer as 'accepted'